# Defining NAN in Visual Basic 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, nan

I was wondering if anyone knows how to define NAN in math.h for Visual Basic 2008 Express?

I was trying to compile SciDAVis with it, but I am getting errors for MuParserScripting.h where it says error C2065 : 'NAN' : Undeclared Identifier.

When I checked the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\math.h I saw that NAN was not declared. I added the following code:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define INFINITY (DBL_MAX+DBL_MAX)
#define NAN (INFINITY-INFINITY)
#endif
```

But that gives me a lot of errors saying: error C2065: 'DBL_MAX' : Undeclared identifier.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Thank!

Comment: It's not clear to me where Visual Basic comes in here... that clearly *isn't* VB...

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, it was supposed to be Visual Studio, not Visual Basic.  I just defined DBL_MAX to be a long double.  That fixed the NAN issue.  Thanks.

Comment: The website below describes how to make the change to math.h.  Just needed to define the new variable.

http://tdistler.com/2011/03/24/how-to-define-nan-not-a-number-on-windows